# Manipulating the quotes on strings when coding in R

Tags: r, string, function, quotes

This is actually a series of questions about the referencing character type of values in R. Would add more bullets when I recalled any other related questions I believe which is interesting and related to this topic. For simplification, here I shall use some simple random examples to explain my questions. Hope this helps:

1. When building up a set of datasets using for loops and wanted to output a series of vectors with names restored in a list called `name_list = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")` in the loop we would like to define as

   ```
   for(i in 1:4){  
       a <- data[data$Year == 2010,]  
       b <- unique(data$Name)  
       c <- summarise(group_by(data,Year,Name), avg = mean(quantity))  
       ...  
       f <- left_join(data,data1, by = c("Year", "Names)  
   }
   ```

Is there any function that allows me to use `function(name_list[1])` through `function(name_list[6])` to replace the a through f in the for loop? This question also goes for trying to create columns using column names in some tables/data frames embedded a chunk of code. (`as.name` and `noquote` function work when just referencing the vector/dataset but don't work when attempting to assign values to the target variable, if possible could anyone share why this happens?)

2. When we extract some information from SQL or other data sources we might have some information separated by comma or some other delimiters as one variable. How could we test if certain values is among one of the values separated by commas? See the example below:

   ```
   1567 %in% c(1567,1456,123)
   TRUE
   a <- "c(1567,1456,123)"
   noquote(a)
   c(1567,1456,123)
   1567 %in% noquote(a)
   FALSE
   1567 %in% list(noquote(a))
   FALSE
   b <- "1567,1456,123"
   noquote(b)
   1567,1456,123
   1567 %in% noquote(strsplit(a,","))
   FALSE
   1567 %in% list(noquote(strsplit(a,",")))
   FALSE
   ```

I kind of get why the `%in%` here doesn't work, seems like R is taking `1567,1456,123` as one element. So I used the `strsplit` to separate them. But seems that it's still not working. Wondering is there any way that allows us to get R taking the string as commands?

Comment: 1 doesn't make much sense. What do you have, and what are you trying to get? 2 starts in a bad situation: you don't want to have code stored as strings. You could use `eval(parse(text = "c(1567,1456,123)"))`, but that structure is very highly discouraged. If, on the other hand, you just have `"1567,1456,123"`, you can just use `strsplit`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification questions, here's what I meant in the original post: 1 is just an example of when I want to assign something referring back from some returning list or some existing variables then if there's any possible way of having these referenced values being assigned new values, I know it's not that necessary, I'm just curious about why or why not. 2 is not really just trying to store code as strings, it's about a have a column of stored values which were separated by commas, I would like to know if the value in another column is one of the values separated by commas.

Comment: There are no quotes in R character values. You are only seeing the "print" function's output. Your second question may be answer either with help("scan") or help("parse"). Multiparty questions are deprecated on SO

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how R store the data. Please correct me if I were wrong, I though R stored character type variables as with quotes no matter print or not but if you output it externally or open the files within R you would not see the quotes(or maybe we can call it invisible quotes?). I really don't know the answer to this and had my wild guess which can be very possibly wrong...

Comment: Quotes in character values? Only if you add them with escape character. Compare "\"abc" to "abc". Use the nchar function.

Comment: When I entered  "\"abc" in R it prints  "\"abc" instead of "abc", nchar( "\"abc") is 4 and nchar("abc") is 3 which makes sense to me. Could you please explain a little bit more about why this supports there's no quote for character values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is convert comma-separated lists like `"1567,1456,123"` into R vectors like `c(1567, 1456, 123)`, you definitely do not need to wrap them in `c(...)` and try to evaluate them directly as vectors. You should just use `strsplit` to split the data:

```
data_str <- "1567,1456,123"
data_vec <- as.integer(strsplit(string_data, ","))
stopifnot(1567 %in% data_vec)
```

Note that `strsplit` returns a *list*, because it can also character vectors of length greater than one:

```
stopifnot(
  all.equal(
    list(c("a", "b"), c("x", "y")),
    strsplit(c("a,b", "x,y"), ",")) == TRUE)
```

which makes it useful for operating on columns of SQL output:

```
| id | concatenated_field |
|----|--------------------|
|  1 |    5362,395,9000,7 |
|  2 |       319,75624,63 |
           (etc.)

d <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2),
  concatenated_field = c("5362,395,9000,7", "319,75624,63"))
d$split_field <- strsplit(d$concatenated_field, ",")
sapply(d, class)
#             id concatenated_field        split_field
#      "numeric"        "character"             "list"
d$split_field[[1]]
# [1] "5362" "395"  "9000" "7"
```

Alternatively, if you're reading in one big stream of comma-separated data, you can use `scan`:

```
data_vec <- scan(
  what = 0,  # arcane way to say "expect numeric input"
  sep = ",",
  text = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10")
stopifnot(all.equal(data_vec, 1:10) == TRUE)
```

`scan` is more heavy-duty than `strsplit` and can handle more complicated inputs as well, such as data with quoted fields:

```
weird_data <- scan(what="", sep=",", text='marvin,ruby,"joe,joseph",dean')
print(weird_data)
# [1] "marvin"     "ruby"       "joe,joseph" "dean"
```

If you are *really really* sure you need to be able to accept and evaluate R code passed as an input (this can be VERY DANGEROUS since it means you will be executing arbitrary unverified R code), you can use

```
r_code_string <- 'c("a", "b"), c("x", "y"))'
stopifnot(
  all.equal(
    c("a", "b"), c("x", "y")),
    eval(parse(r_code_string))) == TRUE)
```

`parse` converts raw text into an unevaluated "expression", which is a representation of R code in the form of a special R object, `eval` passes the expression to the interpreter for execution.

As for `noquote`, it doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't actually modify the string, it just adds a flag to the variable so that it will print without quotation marks. You can emulate this behavior with `print(..., quote = FALSE)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explicit explain. New users would truly have a lot of misunderstandings. Appreciate the patience.

Comment: @Anne thanks for taking the time to explain your problem, give examples, and use good formatting on your question!